# Managed Metadata Navigation Security Trimming

Tags: 2013, navigation, managed-metadata, security-trimming

**Does the managed metadata navigation offer security trimming?**

1. I create a new web and not have anyone have access to it.
2. I would now add a link to that web to the managed metadata navigation.

*Result:* That link is visible for all users - sure when they click on it they are redirected to the `AccessDenied.asxp` page, but doesn't the managed metadata navigation support automatic security trimming for its terms?

Any settings I missed? The only reference I found was on [this German blog](http://msscorner.de/2012/08/26/sharepoint-2013-metadata-navigation/), it says that security trimming is not available. Really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, unfortunatelly it is true, maybe we'll get it in 2017 as such.

> The Managed Metadata based navigation is meant for Global navigation
>   systems, which could cross site collections, not just sites. And so
>   the recommendations are to use it more in a Intranet scenarios where
>   data is purely visible in Read to anyone.

Comment: Do you have any MSDN links to back that up?

Comment: Couldn't find any, my experience with it so far is this, plus several references, see this http://msscorner.de/2012/08/26/sharepoint-2013-metadata-navigation/ (is in German -go through Chrome)

Comment: That blog article was already mentioned by me, but thank you.

Comment: Yes, just realize that, sorry! I wasn't able myself to make it work in a similar scenario.

Comment: How do you apply cross site Collection navigation by Managed metadata. are you going to copy terms and termsets for all site Collections? and will all terms be "Term-Driven Page with Friendy URL"??

Comment: In the cross-site publishing scenarios it is possible http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635879.aspx#BKMK_navtermsets

Answer (score 5):

In SharePoint 2013 it is not possible to build a security trimmed managed metadata navigation. I hope this feature will coming soon with a Cumulative Update or Service Pack. I am the owner of the german blog wich was mentioned here. I think i will provide my article in english too. Sorry for that!!

Answer (score 2):

In Sharepoint Online 2013, I think it is Possible.

> When using the Managed Navigation and modeling the site navigation with Terms, as long as the particular Navigation Term is linked to a page using the Term-Drive Page with Friendly URL option, the term will be displayed to users only if they have the necessary permissions to access the associated page. If you use the Simple Link options instead, the link will be always visible despite what permissions the current user has.

Source: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/wcm-tip-33-managed-navigation-security-trimmed-term-driven-pages/

I tried this and it didn't show me the link on which user is not having the access.

Comment: Please make it very visible when you directly quote other sources

Comment: When using *pages* they are security trimmed - that is actually where MS wants to have you use managed metadata navigation. But there are of course more things in the SharePoint world: Team Sites, document libraries, lists, list views etc. - all of these are not security trimmed.

Answer (score 1):

Managed Navigation does have security trimming, but it's complicated.

Check out my blog where I attempt to clear some things up: https://sharepointycl.wordpress.com/2017/02/27/managing-sharepoint-managed-navigation/

Comment: Thanks for your post, but that couldn't be called security trimming. If you use managed metadata navigation and link to a regular page you get security trimming *of the page* not of the terms themselves. Also this only works for pages and not for all types of links which defeats the purpose of a global navigation.