# Managed Metadata Navigation Security Trimming Conundrum

Tags: permissions, managed-metadata, security-trimming

My organization recently upgraded to SharePoint 2013.  I was excited at the prospect of using managed navigation to display multiple site levels using flyout panels.  After configuring my term set though some of my users are experiencing seemingly strange security trimming.  Some users are having navigation items trimmed even when they have been given read, contribute, design, and sometimes full control of the site and page the term is directed to.  Causing even more confusion for me, other users with similar permissions can see these navigation items...   Site collection administrators, however, can see all terms in the global navigation menu just fine and they all take you to the right place on their respective sites.

All of my terms were configured as 'Term-Driven Page with Friendly URL' and I've specified each site's homepage in 'Change target page for this term' under the Term-Driven Pages tab in each term in the term store.

Am I missing something about how security trimming works with SP13 Managed Metadata Navigation?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you resolved the problem.  I have had the same issue.  The only way I have found around this is to go into each site's "Site Settings" and then go into "Navigation" and press ok.  Every time there is a change to the home page of a site, the security goes away and I need to go through the same process

Answer (score 0):

Managed Navigation does have security trimming, but it's complicated.

Check out my blog where I attempt to clear some things up: https://sharepointycl.wordpress.com/2017/02/27/managing-sharepoint-managed-navigation/

Comment: Please don't add the exact same answer to this question, as you did on [this one](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59822/managed-metadata-navigation-security-trimming/209181#209181). Instead, try to specify your answer further to make it a better of this specific question. Thank You!